# preg_match_all grab everything in a HTML tag when malformatted

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I am trying to automatically grab everything in a special tag in a html string.

What i need to do is grab everything in

```
<font size="8"></font>
```

so that i wrote following preg_match_all

```
preg_match_all('/<font(.*?)size="8"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/font\>/s', $row['html'], $titles,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

however it only works on certain cases only for example following string (Mal-formatted) is failed to match. do you have any idea on how to fix this or to modify above preg with this

```
<font FACE="Times New Roman" SIZE="8"> 
                        <p><font color="#003300">adadas <br>
                        dfsf sdfsdf  <font size="4"><br>
                        <br>
                        gdfgdg 
</font>
</font>
```

Comment: Congos!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!You have actually discovered why html should not be parsed by Re. :)

Comment: there must be a way, if i can pickup everything inside the font size 8 tag then i can strip_tag the inside content to get waht i want isnt it ?

Answer (score 2):

Give something like this a try:

```
<?php

$titles = array(); // CREATE AN ARRAY

$string = '<font FACE="Times New Roman" SIZE="8"><p><font color="#003300">adadas <br>dfsf sdfsdf  <font size="4"><br><br>gdfgdg</font></font>';


$dom_document = new DOMDocument(); // CREATE A NEW DOCUMENT
$dom_document->loadHTML($string); // LOAD THE STRING INTO THE DOCUMENT


// LOOP THROUGH EACH font TAG
foreach ($dom_document->getElementsByTagName('font') as $font_item) {

    // CHECK TO SEE IF IT HAS A SIZE ATTRIBUTE OF 8
    if ($font_item->getAttribute('size') == 8) {
        $titles[] = $font_item->ownerDocument->saveXML($font_item); 
    }

}


print_r($titles);
```

Basically, instead of using REGEX, you can use PHP's built-in DOM Parser.  What this script does is creates a new document named `$dom_document` and loads your string into it.  Then it loops through any `font` tags that it finds and checks to see if any of them have an attribute of `size="8"`.  If it finds any, it grabs the HTML and stores it into the `$titles` array.